# Kivy: Scatter inside scatter

Tags: python, kivy

**Question: How do I put one `Scatter` inside another `Scatter`?**

I have some troubles with kivy's coordinates. In principal I would like to have a `Scatter` in a `Scatter`. They should be drageable (moving first scatter moves everything, moving 2nd scatter moves the 2nd scatter inside the first scatter).

#### Concrete setup

1. I would like to have a base map (scatter 1) that is scaleable and moveable. When we transform this map, everything drawn "on top" of this map should be transformed as well (s.t. it keeps its position on the map).
2. Then I would like to draw a grid on top of the map which is moveable by its own (scatter 2).
3. Then I add some point onto scatter 2.
4. The relative positions must be preserved on rescaling the window.

#### Expected behavior

When I grab scatter 2, it can be moved around and the points (3.) stay relative to scatter 2. When I grab scatter 1, it should move everything s.t. scatter 2 and the points stay where they are on the map (scatter 1).

#### Basic example code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<MyRoot>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                title: ''
                with_previous: True
            ActionOverflow:
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Preferences'
                    on_press: app.open_settings()
    Scatter:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: .2, .2, .3
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Scatter:

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: .8, .2, .3
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Widget:
                pos: 200, 200
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .1, .7, .3
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: 30,50
                        size: 10, 10
"""
Builder.load_string(kv)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()


class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Also here is an image of what's happening. I would like to have the green point fixed on the red scatter and the red scatter sitting inside the violet one:
[image]

#### Approach

I guess I have to transform the coordinates in each step and overwrite the functions `on_touch_...`, maybe using `self.parent.to_parent(*touch.pos)` but unfortunately I don't manage to patch everything together.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rectangle:
    size: self.size
```

This is a relative layout, therefore we need: `pos: 0,0` and not `pos: self.pos`.